# JSONObject Values into another JSONObject with Key Value Pair

Tags: java, json

I've a JSON like this

```
{

      "result":
 {

    "issue_date": "xx-yy-zzzz",
    "father/husband": "TEST",
    "name": "ABC ",
    "blood_group": "",
    "dob": "xx-yy-zzzz",
    "validity": {
      "non-transport": "xx-yy-zzzz to xx-yy-zzzz",
      "transport": "xx-yy-zzzz to xx-yy-zzzz"
    },
    "cov_details": {
      "MCWG": "NA",
      "3WTR": "NA",
      "PSV BUS": "NA",
      "LMV": "NA",
      "INVCRG": "NA"
    },
    "address": "ABC"
  }
}
```

```
     JSONObject dlData = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject dlObj = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject dlcov = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject dlCovs = new JSONObject();
    dlCov = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("cov_details");
```

to access the data of cov_details,
i'm using this code block to store the details present within cov_details Object

```
         dlcov = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("cov_details");
        Iterator<String> x = dlcov.keys();
            while (x.hasNext()){
                String key1 = x.next();
                String value1 = dlcov.optString(key1);
                dlCovs.put("covabbrv",key1);
                dlCovs.put("dcIssuedt",value1);
                dlCovs.put("vecatg",key1);

            }

        dlData.put("dlCovs", dlCovs);
```

i am trying to store every values in dlCovs but it stores only last values in the object, is their anyway using which i can store all the value in dlCovs objet with it's Key value and iterate over it.Any help will be highly appreciable, thanks well in advance.
    enter code here

Comment: Where is `dlCovs` defined?

Comment: shmosel it's another JSONObject defined within the scope only, i forgot to mention that,
JSONObject dlCovs = new JSONObject();

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41455050/edit) your post with any additional code.

Comment: Modified code (y)

Comment: Do you want a JSONObject or a JSONArray as the value of "dlCovs" in dlData? Looks like you would need an array.

Comment: @Remy Anything will work for now, can you tell me how even i can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSONArray` for covabbrv, dcIssuedt and vecatg

```
JSONArray covabbrv = new JSONArray();
JSONArray dcIssuedt = new JSONArray();
JSONArray vecatg = new JSONArray();
Iterator<String> x = dlcov.keys();
    while (x.hasNext()){
        String key1 = x.next();
        String value1 = dlcov.optString(key1);
        covabbrv.put(key1);
        dcIssuedt.put(value1);
        vecatg.put(key1);
    }
dlCovs.put("covabbrv",covabbrv);
dlCovs.put("dcIssuedt",dcIssuedt);
dlCovs.put("vecatg",vecatg);
```

Output would be somthing like:

```
{
    "covabbrv" : ["MCWG", "3WTR", "PSV BUS", "LMV", "INVCRG"],
    "dcIssuedt" : ["NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"],
    "vecatg" : ["MCWG", "3WTR", "PSV BUS", "LMV", "INVCRG"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dlCovs` as a JSONArray, I would do something like this:

```
JSONArray dlCovs = new JSONArray();
dlcov = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("cov_details");
Iterator<String> x = dlcov.keys();
while (x.hasNext()) {
    String key1 = x.next();
    String value1 = dlcov.optString(key1);

    JSONObject currentDlCov = new JSONObject();
    currentDlCov.put("covabbrv",key1);
    currentDlCov.put("dcIssuedt",value1);
    currentDlCov.put("vecatg",key1);

    dlCovs.add(currentDlCov);
}

dlData.put("dlCovs", dlCovs);
```

This will add an array of JSONObjects as a value of `dlCovs` if your `dlData` JSONObject.